# Using limits to prove a function is in the order of another function

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I have to prove the following theorem:

[image]

I am not asking for the whole problem, but am stuck on the first part (Proving that output of c implies g(n) is in the order of f(n)).

I know the following:

> The order of f(n) is the set of complexity functions g(n) for which there exists some positive real constants c and d and some nonnegative integer N such that, for all n >= N:
>   $c * f(n) <= g(n) <= d * f(n)$

At this point, I feel that I may be able to use induction with the formula above to show that the limit of g(n)/f(n) is nonnegative, but I can't quite wrap my head around that. Or perhaps there is another way to show that the limit converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{g(n)}{f(n)}=c$$ 
means that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq n_0:$
$$\left |\frac{g(n)}{f(n)}-c \right | < \epsilon \Rightarrow - \epsilon< \frac{g(n)}{f(n)}-c< \epsilon \Rightarrow c- \epsilon< \frac{g(n)}{f(n)}<c+\epsilon \\ \Rightarrow (c-\epsilon)f(n)< g(n)<(c+\epsilon) f(n)$$

We pick $\epsilon=\frac{c}{2}$ and we have that $\forall n \geq n_0:$

$$\frac{c}{2} \cdot f(n)< g(n)< \frac{3c}{2} \cdot f(n)$$

Now pick $c_1=\frac{c}{2}, c_2=\frac{3c}{2}$ and you will see that this is the definition of $g(n)=\Theta(f(n))$.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you demonstrating each of the steps in between, that made it really easy to follow and understand.

Comment: @McAdam331 You are welcome :)